# Notifications do not arrive to my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My code is in Objective-C

### Firebase side

1. App created
2. [General settings --> done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctLZH.png)
3. [APNs Auth Key --> done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI9ny.png)

### Apple developer account side

1. App ID --> done
2. Dev and Distribution certificates --> done
3. Dev and Distribution profiles --> done

### App side

1. My AppDelegate calls `registerForRemoteNotifications` without any error and the method "`didReceiveRegistrationToken`" is able to return a string like in the following: `NSLog(@"Remote instance ID token: %@", result.token);`
2. First item confirms that my app is able to reach Firebase Server and APNs because a **TOKEN** returns always!
3. I have implemented all functions `didReceiveRemoteNotification` both if I am receiving a notification message while the app is in the background and if it isn't.
4. GoogleService-Info.plist --> moved inside my project

### PROBLEM

The problem is my app is not able to receive any notification I am going to send by using the firebase console. `didReceiveRemoteNotification` never called!

I have read all your feedback on other questions but I didn't solve my problem.

### UPDATE #1

Thank you iDev750 for your answer!

My problem is I do not receive notifications on my app when I send them from the firebase console or directly from my backend. In my opinion if I do not receive a notification it is impossible that didReceiveRemoteNotification is called, are you agree with me?

Anyway, as you said, I sent a push message directly to my token/device and the result is in the following:

{"multicast_id":6185922XXX,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1543141675131005%YYYY"}]}

So, it is sure the message has been sent, otherwise the output should be something like The request's Authentication (Server-) Key contained an invalid or malformed FCM-Token (a.k.a. IID-Token).

I hope I was clear with this my second message. Do you have any idea to help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled added and setted as 'NO'

Answer (score 0):

Here you said two points in your question.

1. Notification is not receiving in your app.
2. didReceiveRemoteNotification never called.

First, which is your problem? becasue both are different issue.

You can do one thing that just install your app in iPhone and paste your device token on Firebase console and send test notification on that device. Just forget about "didReceiveRemoteNotification" method that calling or not.

Now, if you are getting notifications but didReceiveRemoteNotification is not calling then check my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53460880/1673192

If notification is receiving on the device, might be some other issue like -

- Is push notification enable for your AppId created on AppStore?
- Is push notification enable in your app -> Targets -> Capabilities -> Push Notifications

Check these points and let me know still you have any issue.

Comment: Thank you!
I answered in the thread in order to be more clear!