# Why userNotificationCenter didReceive is not fired?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

This is a part of my code. I want to use `UNUserNotificationCenter` and `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to handle notification events.

This code catches the notification event when the app is in a foreground state. But `"didReceive"` is not fired for a background state.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
            [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
    }    
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
        {
            print("willPresent") /// This works
            completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
        }
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            print("didReceive") /// This doesn't work
            completionHandler()
        }
```

But if I don't use `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self` the delegate method is correctly fired in the background.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping FetchCompletionHandler) {
        print("didReceiveRemoteNotification... \(userInfo)")
}
```

How can I use "didReceive"? I want to handle the notification in the background.

Answer (score 3):

`application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` is called when the application receives a silent push notification. Silent push notifications can be delivered in when the application is in the background state, iOS wakes the application to perform background processing invisible to the user.

A silent push notification has the `content-available` flag set to 1.

Silent push notifications should not include an alert, badge, or sound. Silent push is not meant to be visible to the user, it is only a hint to the application that new remote content is available.

Removing the `content-available` flag from your push notification payload will cause iOS to handle it as a regular notification. The user notification center delegate methods will be called instead of `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` but your application will be unable to do background processing triggered by the notification.

You can validate the content of your push notification payload for problems like this using [this tool](https://thenotificationsbook.com/push-payload-check-tool/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case (anymore): "To support a background update notification, make sure that the payload’s aps dictionary includes the content-available key with a value of 1. If there are user-visible updates that go along with the background update, you can set the alert, sound, or badge keys in the aps dictionary, as appropriate." From https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle push notification in my app. I think you need to implement all of these methods to handle all iOS versions in the foreground and background mode.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound,.alert,.badge], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print(deviceTokenString)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to get token; error: \(error)")
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
     //do sth
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
     //do sth
}

// for iOS < 10
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are methods of UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate:

- willPresent: This method gets called when you receive a notification when your app is in the foreground. If the app is in the background then this method will not calls.
- didRecieve: This method gets called when a user clicked on the notification.

In case of background state, only 'didRecieve' will be called when user will click on a notification.